# Where To Start Learning SP 2013 For SP 2010 Developers

Tags: 2010, development, 2013

What are your ideas for beginning to learn(upgrade) to SP 2013 development?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend PluralSight: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses#sharepoint

It does come at a monthly fee. But I get a lot more out of it than I do books. They currently have 53 SharePoint courses and a six part SharePoint 2013 ramp-up series was recently added.